# How to resolve "TargetException:'System.Reflection.TargetException" binding errors when casting a ViewModel to a specific type in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am having trouble with binding in XAML, specifically with casting. Here is an example of the code I am using:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
  <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=ViewModel.(vms:RuleViewModel.Active), UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True"/>
  </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

I want the trigger to fire when a property has a specific value of a specific ViewModel. The ViewModel is an object in C# code that can represent different types of ViewModels. However, when the ViewModel cannot be cast into the type defined in XAML by ViewModel.(vms:SomeType.SomeProperty), it triggers binding errors. The error message is: "Failed to get value. TargetException:'System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type."

My question is: is it okay to do casting in binding like this? Do these errors cause any problems for the app? Although the app works fine, I receive a lot of errors for failed binding. How can I resolve these binding errors?

I tried to solve it by adding type converter like this:

```
internal class TypeToTypeCheckerConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Type expectedType = parameter as Type;
        if (expectedType != null && value != null)
        {
            if(value.GetType() == expectedType)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then using it like this:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
  <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
     <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=ViewModel, Converter={StaticResource TypeConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Type vms:RuleViewModel}}" Value="True"/>
    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=ViewModel.(vms:RuleViewModel.Active), UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True"/>
  </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

But again, it doesn't solve anything as binding error still appears.

Comment: Is `(vms:RuleViewModel.Active)` supposed to be a cast? That's not how bindings work -- that's the syntax for an attached property. You don't need to cast in bindings -- they use reflection, so you'll always have access to all properties on the thing you're binding to. (After all, `DataContext` has type `object`, yet you can still bind to `ViewModel` there...)

Comment: Also note that `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` makes no sense here. It has no effect in a OneWay Binding, and it has nothing to do with the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: What's wrong with `{Binding Path=ViewModel.Active}`?

Comment: @mm8 I used the syntax above to force the XAML editor in WPF to show properties in a floating window, so that I can clearly see which properties are available for a certain object. Since the ViewModel object can be of any type, the XAML editor in Visual Studio may not display all available properties for the object, because it doesn't know the specific type of the object. Using the syntax above helps me see all available properties for the object, which can be helpful when designing the UI in XAML. Sorry if I didn't mentioned that in original question.